# A Dragon Ball Z/GT fanfiction where characters are fighting in an interdimensional tournament

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, dragon-ball-z, manga, dragonball-gt

I remember reading some scanned materials on a website, which I believe were fanfiction because of how non-canon the story sounded. These scans were in French, though I don't know if it was translated from another language or not.

I can't remember exactly when I read those, but it was approximately 6 to 12 years ago (between 2008 and 2012), which is way before Dragon Ball Super.

These scans were in black and white. I don't remember any colour.

None of these included adult content.

The story seemed to be some form of interdimensional tournament between Dragon Ball characters.

The first fight I saw depicted Salza (Cooler's Armoured Squadron captain) fighting against an old Krillin wearing a heavy turtle shell (he was old, much like the Dragon Ball GT version, but he was wearing a shell like Muten Roshi did in Dragon Ball).

Salza is (somehow) outpowered. When he was about to use his Energy Blade (which he claimed could cut through everything), Krillin simply threw a Kienzan, which killed him.

After the battle, Goku approached the old Krillin to greet him, but the latter dismissed him, telling him something in the line of "I don't know any of you Saiyajin" in a rather despising way.

Another scene included two girls enthusiastically talking to each others (possibly two different version of Bra, Vegeta's daughter). One was saying how much she likes shopping, whilst the other was telling how much she likes to fight. But when they both looked the other way, they muttered how unfashionable the other girl was.

The next fight was going to include Broly, who provoked some turmoil as they, seemingly, released him from... some form of stasis (tube?).

Either before or during the fight, a flashback showed the Z fighters against Broly, much like the Dragon Ball Z OAV/OVA where they fight Broly, except that Gohan was still standing and holding ground (Vegeta commented how strong that child was), while Goku was charging a Genkidama. When he threw it toward Broly, the latter simply deflected it toward the comet which blew off. Then the fighters claimed that Broly seemingly disappeared.

Suddenly, Broly noticed Goku. He was about to charge toward him (who possibly turned SSJ3). But then he was interrupted by a solid yellow beam (the same which Vegito used to pierce through Buu's mouth). Broly looked, and noticed Super Vegito, waiting to fight him.

An important detail in this fight: the longer it took, the stronger Broly became.

At first, Vegito was able to outpower Broly and kick him. But then Broly became stronger. Then Vegito turned SSJ2, to which some spectators (or the Z Fighters) commented: "We haven't seen Vegito turning SSJ2 since... Wait a minute... he never turned SSJ2!". For a short period, he had the upper hand again; until Broly became stronger again and kicked him.

An audio speaker stated how the spectators took some damage, because of how powerful the fighters were (and 1% of their power went through the barrier protecting the spectators).

When Vegito came out of the dust, to everyone's surprise, he visibly took some damages. He stated something about finishing it, before turning SSJ3.

Suddenly, the spectators were dragged toward Vegito. Someone stated that because of his power level, it had some gravity effect or something. Then the audio speaker stated that they increased the overall gravity to compensate it.

Vegito then used a high energy attack to kick Broly far away into outer space.

Meanwhile, some of the Z Fighters were hurt. Someone offered to heal them, since they "have namekian healers", but they refused, stating that the namekian healers wouldn't be strong enough. Besides, they "have senzus".

The last bit I read included a tall Buu stating that he was awaiting for this opportunity. He teleported to Broly's inconscious body, preparing to absorb him. But then someone appeared to stop him, though I can't remember exactly who.

The story wasn't over yet. I simply stopped reading from that point on.

Comment: Just to be clear, this was a comic, probably fanmade?

Comment: Kind of, though "manga" would be a more appropriate term, judging by the Japanese-ish drawing.

Comment: "Doujinishi", or "doujin" are the general term for knockoff works FWIW. It's most commonly used to refer to comics (Japanese copyright is much looser than that of the United States, so it's much more acceptable to make and market your own work in a licensed universe. In fact, many manga artists either started that way, or even continue making unlicensed comics for properties they officially draw for), but it's also used for software ("Doujin games") and even has a sub-genre of "Doujin Fighter" involving fighting games with many properties (even some nonfighting ones, like mascots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be Dragon Ball Multiverse
http://www.dragonball-multiverse.com/

It's about a multiverse tournament and it has Vegito turning SS3 to defeat Broly.
[image: Vegito is seen charging and firing a powerful energy blast, shouting "Final Dragon Flash"]
[image: The energy blast that Vegito fired toward Broly is taking the shape of a dragon; Broly stops in his flight, surprised]

Comment: I confirm it is Dragon Ball Multiverse. I have been reading it for a while and I remember every scene in the OP. For example, Kulilin's fight starts here: www.dragonball-multiverse.com/fr/page-141.html . The two Bra talking to each other is the cover of chapter 11: http://www.dragonball-multiverse.com/fr/page-213.html